# Error with JSONP {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"}

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I send a commande to external server to the url, i got {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"} on html code. but in console i got the good data you can see on the image.

#### Any help?

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste image.Paste your code+output+what error you are getting + what expected outcome you want , here in your question itself.

Comment: i have no error, the output just {“readyState”:4,“status”:200,“statusText”:“load”}. now it works with the modification gived by muttalebm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the result in the json callback string.
Use `echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.$result.')';`